# Defining a relation that is antisymmetric, but not symmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Say I have a set = {1,2,3}.

I am trying to think about how I could define a set on X which is antisymmetric but not symmetric.

At first I had thought the set would be Z = {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)} but am I correct in thinking that this is symmetric?

Would the set Z = {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(2,3)} be both antisymmetric, but not symmetric? Since the (1,1),(2,2) and (3,3) make it antisymmetric, but the fact that (2,1) and (3,2) are missing making it not symmetric?

Thanks

Comment: Clarify please: your use of the words "both antisymmetric" means there must be some "and ....".

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $R$ is a relation on a set $E$ which is both symmetric and antisymmetric.

Take $a\in E$. Assume you can find $b\in E$ such that $aRb$. By symmetry you get $bRa$. Hence by antisymmetry $a=b$. The same thing holds with $bRa$.

Whence an element is, at most, in relation with itself. So the diagonal set and its subsets are the only example of relation being both symmetric and antisymmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \{1,2,3\}$. We want a relation $R$ on $A$ that is antisymmetric, but not symmetric. This means that

- **antisymmetry**: for every $(a,b) \in R$ where $a \neq b$, we must also have $(b,a) \notin R$, and
- **not symmetric**: there must exist some $(a,b) \in R$ such that $(b,a) \notin R$.

Your suggestion is $R = \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(2,3)\}$. Let us check if this satisfies the criteria. There are two pairs that satisfies $(a,b) \in R$ with $a \neq b$, namely $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$. We see that $(2,1) \notin R$ and $(3,2) \notin R$, so it is antisymmetric. Can we say that it is not symmetric? Yes, because $(1,2) \in R$ but $(2,1) \notin R$.

We can make a smaller example by taking some small antisymmetric relation and adding an element to make it not symmetric. We could take $R = \{(1,1)\}$ as an antisymmetric set, and then introduce for example $(1,2)$ to make it not symmetric, so that $R = \{(1,1),(1,2)\}$ is still antisymmetric because $(2,1) \notin R$ and it is not symmetric because $(1,2) \in R$, but $(2,1) \notin R$.

Answer (score 0):

How about $$Z=\{(1,2), (2,3),(3,1)\}$$

Comment: Isn't this symmetric?

Comment: I edited my answer and see [anti symmetric relations](https://www.google.lk/search?biw=1366&bih=643&q=antisymmetric+relations&spell=1&sa=X&ei=GWEnVYabJcz78QWC5YHgAQ&ved=0CBgQBSgA) and [symmetric relations](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSymmetric_relation&ei=lWEnVZHSJs3M8gXHyYDoAQ&usg=AFQjCNHP0bPgDX_iaGOczOSIPMPIqZXKOA)

Answer (score 0):

How about '$\le$' (the less than or equal relation)?